# How to refresh map screen in a Kotlin app after enabling permissions in settings screen?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps

Once enabling the permissions in settings for google map, on back to the application screen is not getting refreshed. what is the call back need to be used ?

> ```
> binding.mapView.permissionMsgClick.setOnClickListener {
>             val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
>             val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", requireContext().packageName, null)
>             intent.data = uri
>             startActivity(intent)
>             Log.d(TAG, "permissionMsgClick : entering")
>         }
> ```
>
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOreG.png)
> In the above image i have a location text after enabling permissions from settings on navigate back map screen is not refreshing. So the texts are not hiding am using the fragment class.

Comment: have you tried starting the activity again ?

Comment: with startactivity and intent ?

Comment: Yes i have tried still not refreshed. @BinilGeorge